# Postgres error codes

Tags: postgresql

How can I translate textual postgres error messages into error codes?

For example:

```
permission denied for relation table
```

How can I find out which error code it belongs to here? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `log_line_prefix` setting in `postgresql.conf`. Make sure you use this `%e` option to log the codes in your postgres logs.

`%e` = SQL state

You can also use `\set VERBOSITY verbose` in `psql` to see detailed errors with `SQLSTATE` there.